# expand an array in react js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, loops

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.expand();
  }
componentDidMount(){}
expand(){
var re = [];
this.state.reservation1.length = 9;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.reservation1.length; i++) {
     if(this.state.reservation1[i]){
       re[i]=this.state.reservation1[i]
       }
        else {
           re[i]= this.state.reservation1[i]=
              {name:"",active:false,dayindex:0}
            }
        }
   console.log(re)
  console.log(re.dayindex)

   }



constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    reservation1:[
      {name:"8:30",active:true,dayindex:1},
      {name:"jad",active:true,dayindex:3},
      {name:"tony",active:true,dayindex:4},
      {name:"",active:false,dayindex:6},
    ],
    reservations:[]
  };
  this.expand=this.expand.bind(this);
}
```

RE RETURN AN ARRAY OF 9 OBJECTS 
re.dayindex is undefined 
can someone help please

i am trying to expand this array to reorder it by dayindex 
any solution will be pleased

Comment: and also reservation1.dayindex is undefined

Comment: `re` is an array, so you need to access it as an array as well. `re[0].dayindex`

Comment: You should use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) to update the state outside of the constructor. And you should [not mutate](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an object under in an array. So it should be `re[i].dayindex` , i being your index.

P.S: You should try not to mutate things in javascript, it really makes your code vulnerable. `re[i]= this.state.reservation1[i]` ?

Maybe you can try this code:-

```
const re = [];
const reservation1 = [
      {name:"8:30",active:true,dayindex:1},
      {name:"jad",active:true,dayindex:3},
      {name:"tony",active:true,dayindex:4},
      {name:"",active:false,dayindex:6},
    ];



  reservation1.map((datum,index)=> {
    if (datum) {
      re.push(datum)
    } else {
      re.push({
        name: "",
        active: false,
        dayIndex: 0
      });
    }
  })

  console.log(re[1].dayindex);
```

Comment: Sorry I’m new to js what do you mean by mutation

Comment: https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa .. let me know if you need anything else :)